# Distributive lattices with periodic Coxeter matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, lattice-theory

Let $L$ be a finite distributive lattice and $U$ its incidence matrix with entries $u_{i,j}=1$ iff $i \leq j$ and $u_{i,j}=0$ else.
Then $U^{-1}$ is the Moebius matrix of $L$ and $C_L:=- U^{-1} U^{T}$ is the Coxeter matrix of $L$.

> Question: For which $L$ is the Coxeter matrix periodic, that is $C_L^n$ is the identity matrix for some $n$?

Call such a lattice (or its incidence algebra) periodic. For example any divisor lattice (products of chains) is periodic.
For distributive lattices on $r \geq 2$ points, the number of periodic distributive lattices starts with 1,1,2,3,5,7,11,8,15 for $r \leq 10$ and oeis finds this : https://oeis.org/A053724 .

> Question: Is this still true for $r=11$?

Algebras with periodic coxeter matrix are studied in representation theory of quivers, see for example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505001709 and several other articles.

One might also ask what the period is for a given lattice. For example for the Boolean lattice of $n$ points it is 3 if n is odd and 6 if n is even.
Recall that the free distributive lattice is the lattice of order ideals of the Boolean lattice.

> Question: For which $n$ is the free distributive lattice on $n$ points periodic and what is the period in case it is? It is periodic with period 4 for $n=1$, period 10 for $n=2$ and with period 6 for $n=3$ and with period 42 for $n=4$.

Some tests suggest that the lattice of order ideals of a divisor lattice is also periodic.

Comment: If these two sequences were equal it would be really strange...

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Yes, probably one or two more cases might be enough to rule it out. But sadly I can not generate all distributive lattices with $r=11$ points with SAGE anymore, since SAGE filters those out of all posets which is too big.

Comment: Is there a particular significance (e.g. in algebra) to the Coxeter matrix being periodic?

Comment: @SamHopkins I added a reference.

Comment: How do you test for periodicity?

Comment: @MartinRubey I wrote you an email with the code. It can be done with SAGE (coxeter transformation exists for SAGE) or with GAP, which I used for the data here.

Comment: Apparently, the sequence begins with $1,1,2,3,5,7,11,8,15,19$, which is not in the OEIS.  (I checked periodicity with an upper bound of 1000).

Comment: @MartinRubey Thank you very much! Too bad.